# Listing user associated permission in django 2.2.5

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I want to list all the permissions that my user has be it a custom permission or default permission

what I have tried till now

1. **request.user.user_permissions**
2. **request.user.get_all_permissions**
3. **permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=request.user)**

But none of them returned any permissions though the user was a superuser, staff and active

Any lead and help will be great

Comment: Superusers do not have any related permission, in the permission checkers the test will simply return `True` for an admin user.

Comment: is there any way i can get the list for their permission as well

Comment: but the entire point of a superuser is that you do *not* give them permissions, the `.has_perm(...)` method will simply return `True` for *all* permissions, even permissions that do *not* exist. You thus can retrieve these for a superuser with `Permission.objects.all()`.

Comment: i understood what you meant but still isn't there a way to list the permissions for all users

Comment: superusers do not "own" any permission, simply because these are superusers, there are no restrictions. So there are no *specific* permissions attached to that user.

Answer (score 1):

An admin user normally has no permissions assigned to them, the [**`.has_perm(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) will always return `True`, or [as the documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm):

> Returns `True` if the user has the specified permission, where perm is in the format `"<app label>.<permission codename>"`. (see documentation on permissions). If the user is inactive, this method will always return `False`. **For an active superuser, this method will always return `True`**.

So the admin user is not assigned all permissions (this would also be "error-prone" since later new permissions can pop up, and it would thus require extra logic to add these to the superusers that already exist.

Comment: but i want to list down permisions for all my users be it admin as well is there any way I can achieve that? just to mention that I have read your answer and still  want to achieve this

Comment: @SachinRajput: for an admin user, that would be `Permission.objects.all()`. But one would also expect that for a non-active user it is a list of no permissions, but if you use an inactive one, the permissions will still be there.

Comment: thats fine so what you are suggesting is the 3rd option that I listed and I should return all if the user is super admin